# Xcode: Integer in two files in new xcode beta

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using one integer in two `.m` files, but it is stopping the code from running saying:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It says Duplicate Symbols and states my integer. Code runs fine if the integer is only in one file.

How do I fix this so that I can use the same integer in two `.m` files?

Comment: Do you want the value shared in different places or are you just trying to reuse the name to be different things?

Comment: I want it shared so that if I change the value in one file, I can use the new value in a different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few use scenarios:

1) The variable is a constant

You should declare the variable with `const`

```
const int variableName = 42;
```

2) The variable is a global variable shared by multiple files

You should declare the variable with `extern` in header file and define the variable in *one* of the .m file

```
// .h file
extern int variableName;

// in one of the .m file
int variableName = 42;
```

3) You want each file have its own copy of the variable. Change the variable in `file1.m` won't not affect the variable in `file2.m`

```
static int variableName = 42;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Scenario 2 worked perfectly. So I declare extern int on all of the .h of the files I'm using and declare it as just an int in only one of the .m files. Does it make a difference which .m  I declare it in?

Comment: It doesn't make much difference. But to whatever file make sense to you.